# Scalar Yukawa Theory in non-relativistic limit

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

I'm new to QFT, and am enrolled in a class at my school. I feel as though the teacher didn't give us the tools to tackle this problem yet. It's only the second week and we've gone through at most chapter 2, and maybe a little of 3, in Peskin in Schroeder.

I would just like some help on what tools to even use to start this problem, or where to look. The Lagrangian is 
$$\mathcal{L} = |\partial_{\mu}\phi|^2 - M^2|\phi|^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}h)^2 -\frac{m_h^2}{2}h^2  + \lambda h\phi\phi^*$$ where $\phi$ is a charged complex scalar field and $h$ is a real neutral scalar field. The first question asks to compute the amplitude for $\phi\phi\rightarrow \phi\phi$ scattering via single $h$ exchange in the limit of non-relativistic $\phi$ and deduce from this the quantum-mechanical potential (which after some research I believe to be the Yukawa potential).

My idea so far is to somehow use the Born approximation, but I'm not really sure where I can even begin. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: This model is discussed in detail in Coleman's famous QFT lectures. See here: http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm just surprised that solving this problem requires so much machinery that we haven't developed in class.

Comment: It is not that complicated (I don't know what was done in your class). Just read the October 23 lecture.